# Complex matrix multiplication OpenCL

Tags: matrix, opencl, complex-numbers

i’m a new programmer on opencl, i’ve to perform a multiplication of 2 complex matrix but i don’t know how to deal with complex matrix on opencl. please any help? 
 I aleady tried matrix multiplication  with normal numbers.

Comment: To better assist you should add some code to your question. Something which worked on so far, just for context.

Answer (score 0):

One way, though probably not the most efficient, would be to regard your complex matrix, Z say as being two real matrices X (the real parts) and Y the imaginary parts,ie

```
X[i,j]= Real( Z[i,j]) Y[i,j] = Imag( Z[i,j])
```

If you have another complex matrix W say, which is split as above into U and V then to multiply:

```
Z*W = (X*U-Y*V, X*V+Y*U)
```

where on the rhs we have real matrices and real matrix multiplication and addition.

In terms of multiplies and adds this will be the same amount of computation as doing the complex multiplications and additions (of the elements) directly. The inefficiency will come if you are given, and should return, arrays of complex numbers; then you have to split, as above the matrices you are going to multiply into real ones, and combine the product into complex array.